# ViewPager OnSingleTapConfirmed - Get clicked page index

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager

I need some help with getting index of clicked (tapped) page. 
Current UI is implemented using custom ViewPager so that it acts as a carousel with protruding pages. I need to be able to change current page with scrolling motion, but I want to add option for "clicking", as in if user taps on protruding page that page becomes active.

I've got the following listener:

```
public override bool OnSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
{
   return false;
}
```

I even have saved view captured inside on touch method:

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
   touchedView = v;
   tapGestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);

   return false;
}
```

But I don't know how to get index of the tapped on page. Any help would be appreciated.

Please bear in mind that I'm not too familiar with android platform, so I'm aware that maybe my way of doing things is not correct.

Comment: Are you using viewpager with fragments or views?

Comment: @Ben P. With fragments (FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: Hi, by `it acts as a carousel with protruding pages`, I can't understand it, do you want to get the fragment's index when you click on it?